# error 1084: expecting leftbrace before left paren

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

```
package
{
    import flash.events.* 
    import flash.ui.*

    public class tank () //1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before leftparen.
    {
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

This is a recurring bugger of an error that i can't figure out and it seems to be the one version of error 1084 I can't find by googling...

I tried putting the left brace after that line before the parenthesis and before the whole line, other errors...

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. If you're trying to make a class, you need to get rid of the left and right parenthesis (like the error is telling you, you're giving it the wrong input and its expecting a left brace (`{`)). So, try the following:

```
package
{
import flash.events.*; // Put a semi-colon after imports
import flash.ui.*; // Here too

//public class tank () // 1084: Syntax error: expecting leftbrace before leftparen.
public class tank // This should not error on you.
{
     //other stuff
}
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

A class definition does not utilise parenthesis. *You may be confusing the class definition with the constructor*, which does use parenthesis and is nested within the class.

Basically, just remove the `()` at the end of here:

```
public class tank
```

And then your constructor would be within that using the parenthesis like so:

```
public class tank
{
    // This is a constructor. It is a public method with the same name as
    // the class it is defined within, and is called when an instance of
    // this class is created.
    public function tank()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also thanks to @ThePhD Thanks, I will never feel the same now that I used the @ symbol... Don't know constructors unless that's a fancy name for functions but I must have been mixing them up with functions. Thanks.

Comment: @user1743752 Constructor is just a *function with the same name as the class that defines it*. You put code in there that you want to run immediately when you create a new instance of your class.